# Border radius is not working in safari 4.0,5.0 for windows 7 and later versions

Tags: html, image, css

iam adding border radius to picture ,but when i run browser testing using browser stack i found out like Safari 5.0 and below versions for windows 7 & 8 are not supporting `border-radius` property.The image is showing as a square one

below the html part

```
 <div class='profileDet'>
   <img src='/img/eg.png' alt='image' id='circleImg'>
   <div class='profileTile'><h>Title</h></div>
 </div>
```

and my css

```
#circleImg{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;

/* for safari lower versions*/
-webkit-border-radius:50px;

}
```

Comment: `border-radius` is an CSS3 property and so lower versions of the browsers may not support. Please refer http://caniuse.com/border-radius for details on browser support.

Comment: i got solution i will post it

Answer (score 0):

This should in fact work. Don't forget to add `overflow: hidden`. This will ensure your background does not appear below the rounded effect corners.

```
#circleImg{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;
overflow: hidden;
/* for safari lower versions*/
-webkit-border-radius:50px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

added these lines

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
```

and now its working !! thank you guys.